# I'm plotting my data in R but the legend is not there although I have typed in the command lines

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm plotting my data but the legend doesn't show up. I've included the legend command line and can't find any solution as I think the command is correct.

I use the data from stock market.

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)
tckrs<-c("GOOG","FB")
getSymbols(tckrs,from="2019-01-01")
AdG<-Ad(GOOG)
AdF<-Ad(FB)
DrG<-dailyReturn(AdG)[-1,]
DrF<-dailyReturn(AdF)[-1,]
portfolio<-cbind(DrG,DrF)
colnames(portfolio)
names(portfolio)[1]<-"DrG"  
names(portfolio)[2]<-"DrF"  

tsRainbow<-rainbow(ncol(portfolio))
plot(x=portfolio,ylab="Return",main="Portfolio Returns (Single)",col=tsRainbow,screens=1)  
legend(x="bottom",legend=c("GOOG","FB"),lty=1,col=tsRainbow)

#I also tried

myColors<-c("red","darkgreen")
plot(x=portfolio[,"DrG"],xlab="Time",ylab="Stock Returns",main="Stock Returns",ylim=c(-0.15,0.1),major.ticks= "years",minor.ticks=FALSE,col="red")
lines(x=portfolio[,"DrF"],col="darkgreen")
legend(x="bottom",legend=c("DrG","DrF"),lty=1,col=myColors)
```

The plot does come out but there is no legend at all from those two commands.

Comment: it seems the legend has problems with the date object. you can see this by using `show(legend(.....))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `xts` package does strange things in its plots.  You are supposed to call `addLegend` instead of `legend`.  For your example, replace the `legend` call with

```
addLegend("bottom", c("GOOG", "FB"), lty=1, lwd=c(2,1), 
          col = c("red", "darkgreen"), bty="o")
```

[image: screen shot]